# Here Maps 'segmentRef' attribute explanation

Tags: here-api, heremaps

Can someone explain/point to documentation that explains the 'segmentRef' attribute that gets returned by the Here Routing API v8 when spans="segmentRef". An example of what gets returned is shown below. The middle part seems to be the topologyID but I can't figure out the rest. Thanks.

```
$0:321534451:$1:457679505#-0..0.7675126869621484
```

Answer (score 0):

In v8, segmentRef is returned instead of PVID. spans conceptually replace link attributes.

Please refer the screenshots of supported link attributes.

[image]

[image]

For more details please refer the below api guide.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/migration_guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

`segmentRef` is a parameter used in the HERE Maps API to identify a specific segment of a route. The `segmentRef` parameter is used to reference a specific segment within the route, and can be used in conjunction with the HERE Routing API to retrieve information about that segment. The information that can be retrieved for a segment includes details such as the start and end coordinates, the length of the segment, and the type of road along which the segment is located.

The `segmentRef` parameter is typically used in conjunction with other parameters, such as `origin` and `destination`, to define the overall route and retrieve information about specific segments within that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it into two parts:

The first part: $0:321534451:$1:457679505)

It finds the corresponding catalogs, layers, and segment info.

Second one: "#-0..0.7675126869621484" (Topology segments metadata)

direction format:

```
* This is an undirected or bidirectional segment.
+ This is a directed segment following the pre-defined segment direction (forward direction). The pre-defined segment direction is the one going from the start node to the end node as defined in the source catalog.
- This is a directed segment following the opposite direction (backward direction).
? The segment has an unknown direction.
```

range format: {startOffset}..{endOffset}

point format: offset

$0:321534451:$1:45767950 -->$0(catalog), 321534451(PartitionID),$1(Layer), 45767950(segment) I don't think you have to worry about this part.

-0..0.7675126869621484 --> backward direction, startoffset 0, endofseet 0.7675126869621484